# tinkerpop driver - janusgraph lose data - new vertex is not stored

Tags: tinkerpop, janusgraph

I try to add data to an existing janusdb on cassandra storage.

I use tinkerpop driver.

In this way i create a traversal:

```
g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(host,port,"g"));
```

And in this way I add user

```
g.addV("User").properties("name",name).hasNext();
```

Then i try to recover user from DB

```
g.V().has("name",user).values("name")
```

But user not found

Same result from gremlin console

```
graph.addVertex(label, 'User', 'name', 'ciro2')
```

If i search user in same session i find it. If I close session and restart console I can't found user.

Ok after using commit command, the data persist in database, but only from console.

```
graph.tx().commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EMBEDDED SOLUTIONS**

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open(cassandraConfigPath);
g = graph.traversal();
```

Where cassandraConfigPath points to file

janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties

and its content:

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true
```

Finally I can add a vertex using this code:

```
g.addV("User").property("name", f).next();
g.getGraph().tx().commit();
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to  Florian Hockmann' comment i found solution too for remote server. When i asked the question, I did use the version 3.4.4 of tinkerpop driver. This can not load conf/remote-objects.yaml file. When I did update library to 3.4.6 all works fine.

**REMOTE SOLUTION**

```
g = traversal().withRemote(gremlinServerConfigPath);
graph = g.getGraph();
```

where gremlinServerConfigPath is file:///full.qualified.name.properties

and content

```
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

conf/remote-objects.yaml (under resource folder)

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

In this case commit is not necessary

Comment: Did you try that traversal without the commit in the second line with the first method you mentioned in your question, e.g., by connecting `withRemote` instead of by creating a graph with `JanusGraphFactory.open`? I think the issue in your original setup was that you used `hasNext()` instead of `next()` or `iterate()`. Otherwise it should work like that.

Comment: I have tried many things. Each with a problem. This solution works. Is not it correct in your opinion?

Comment: No, your solution is correct, but it's using JanusGraph embedded whereas you have first used JanusGraph Server and connected via `withRemote` which is the recommended way actually. I wrote about advantages and disadvantages of both approaches [in this thread in the janusgrah-users Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-users/t7gNBeWC844/gW7QzowECAAJ).

Comment: In cassandra config I specify remote connection. Why you assert that is embedded?

Comment: Embedded JanusGraph, not embedded Cassandra. It simply means that you call the JanusGraph API directly in your application. If you use JanusGraph Server instead, then all Gremlin traversals are sent over the network to the server for execution. That is the remote mode I'm talking about.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will try this GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote('conf/remote-graph.properties') for remote ??